# To determine how fast is our code is executing and we use timeit cellular magical func

Tags: python, pandas

```
%%timeit -n 100
grades = pd.Series([90,80,60,46])
total =0
for i in grades:
    total+=i
total/len(grades)
```

this code raises an error as UsageError: Line magic function
`%%timeit` not found.

Comment: Welcome to the SO! Try writing understandable questions in order to get answers: you haven't really stated the definition of timeit function and what you want to achieve with this code

Answer (score 0):

`%%timeit` is a [magic command for ipython/jupyter](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

If you are using a classical script, you need to import and use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module:

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd

timeit.timeit('''grades = pd.Series([90,80,60,46])
total =0
for i in grades:
    total+=i
total/len(grades)''',
              number=100, globals=globals())
```

Comment: Okay thanks, will do so...